# Is $\{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$ connected in $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, connectedness, path-connected

> Is $\{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$ connected in  $\mathbb{C}^2$ ?

How do I approach this problem ?

I think that that the fact that continuous functions map connected sets to connected sets might be helpful.

But I am having trouble using it. What function should I use ?

I thought of $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^2$ defined as $f(z) = (z, \sqrt{1-z^2})$. But that won't suffice since there are points of the form $(z, -\sqrt{1-z^2})$ as well. What should I do ?

> Also, what can we say about the path-connectedness of the set ?

Any help shall be highly appreciated.

Comment: From a branch of $\sqrt{1-z^2}$ continuous on a curve $a\to 1$ there is a curve connecting your point $(a,b)$ to $(1,0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *stereographic projection* which holds for any field $K$ (your case being that of $K=\mathbb{C}$). 
For $(x,y)\in K^2$ with $x^2+y^2=1$ and $y\not=1$, setting $t=\frac{x}{1-y}$, one gets $$x=\frac{2t}{t^2+1},\ y=\frac{t^2-1}{t^2+1}$$
Geometric insights can be found [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) (well, it is 3-dimensional but you can put $z=0$ for your 2-dimensional case). Then any point of your complex curve
$x^2+y^2=1$ with $y\not=1$ can be connected to $(0,-1)$ ($t=0$), $(1,0)$ ($t=1$) and $(-1,0)$ ($t=-1$). If your starting point is $(0,1)$ then exchange $x$ and $y$ and use connection with $(0,-1)$ as intermediate point. Then, through this very intuitive parametrization, you get the fact that your curve (the complexified cercle) is connected.